# How to handle shared files and folders vis symbolic link within a git repository

Tags: git, github, repository

I have project I want to store in a git repository and put into github where the substructure of the tree currently has a symbolic link shared folder for common code (contained within the tree - not outside of the tree) between top level folders and the tree.

Example:

```
.                  - top level project for repo where .git lives
folderA            
  sharedFolder     - real folder
folderB
  sharedFolder -> ../folderA/sharedFolder  - symbolic link folder to avoid duplicate files
```

Can this be done and how?

I would consider making the content of the sharedFolder its own git repo if that makes for a solution where I can still avoid duplicating code between the content needed in folderA and folderB - if I do that, how would setup the two git repos for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

If you put `sharedFolder` in its own git repository, you can do `git submodule add sharedFolder` in each repository that uses it.

For more information, you should look up the `git submodule` command.

Github has more information about submodules [here](http://help.github.com/submodules/).